# Jolt Conditional Flag Based on JSON Fields

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have a JSON input as below

**Scenario 1**:

```json
{
  "accountType": "Admin",
  "accountInformation": {
    "user": "internal",
    "source": "Facebook",
    "internalAccount": "false"
  }
}
```

**output.json**

```json
{
  "userFlag":true
}
```

I need to derive a **userFlag** in Java, which should be **true** only when the user is "**internal**" and the source is "**Facebook**". If the user is **null** or the source is other than "**Facebook**," the userFlag should be set to the value of internalAccount.

**Scenario 2:**

```json
{
  "accountType": "Admin",
  "accountInformation": {
    "user": "internal",
    "source": "Google",
    "internalAccount": "false"
  }
}
```

**output.json**

```json
{
  "userFlag":false
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accountInformation": {
        "source": {
          "Facebook": {
            "#true": "sourceFlag"
          }
        },
        "user": {
          "internal": {
            "#true": "userInternalFlag"
          }
        },
        "internalAccount": "userFlag"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "result": "=equals(@(1,sourceFlag),@(1,userInternalFlag))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "userFlag": "=equals(@(1,result), 'true')"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "userFlag": "=toBoolean(@(1,userFlag))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "sourceFlag": "",
      "userInternalFlag": "",
      "result": ""
    }
  }
]
```

producing **the output**:

```json
{
  "userFlag" : true
}
```

but when for this input shouldn't produce **value** as

```json
{
  "accountType": "Admin",
  "accountInformation": {
    "user": "",
    "source": "Facebook",
    "internalAccount": false
  }
}
```

**actual**:

```json
{
  "userFlag" : true
}
```

**expected**:

```json
{
  "userFlag" : false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below Jolt spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "accountInformation": {
        "user|source": "null"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accountInformation": {
        "user": {
          "internal": {
            "@2,source": {
              "Facebook": {
                "#true": "userFlag"
              },
              "*": {
                "@4,internalAccount": "userFlag"
              }
            }
          },
          "*": {
            "@2,internalAccount": "userFlag"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Glad to hear! 
But you have to accept the solution so that others can also benefit from it.

Comment: Agree Barbarosh!